# Am I losing rows in map-reduce process?

Tags: mongodb, mapreduce

I have a table with 604 rows and I am trying to launch a mapreduce, but I am getting some strange results. 
This is a simplified version, the command result.total=values.length should be return 604 instead of 5. Could you help me to get the error in this code?

```js
db.foo.mapReduce(
        function() {
            emit("ALL" , this.libres)
        },
        function(key, values) { 
            result = {total: 0,count:0};
            result.total=values.length;
            for (var i= 0; i < values.length; i++) {
                  if (values[i]==0){result.count++}
            }
            return result
        },
        {out:{inline:1}})



  {
    "results" : [
            {
                    "_id" : "ALL",
                    "value" : {
                            "total" : 5,
                            "count" : 0
                    }
            }
    ],
    "timeMillis" : 26,
    "counts" : {
            "input" : 604,
            "emit" : 604,
            "reduce" : 7,
            "output" : 1
    },
    "ok" : 1
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [MongoDB mapReduce docs](http://docs.mongodb.org/master/reference/command/mapReduce/#mapreduce-map-cmd),

> Because it is possible to invoke the reduce function more than once
>   for the same key, the following properties need to be true:
>
> the type of the return object must be identical to the type of the
>   value emitted by the map function.
>
> the reduce function must be
>   associative. The following statement must be true:

```
reduce(key, [ C, reduce(key, [ A, B ]) ] ) == reduce( key, [ C, A, B ] )
```

> the reduce function must be idempotent. Ensure that the following
>   statement is true:

```
reduce( key, [ reduce(key, valuesArray) ] ) == reduce( key, valuesArray )
```

Your reduce function does not satisfy those conditions, and according to the output `"reduce" : 7`, the reduce function was called 7 times.

Your mapper only outputs 1 key, `"ALL"`, so the reduce function was called 7 times for this key, the later invocations taking in the outputs of previous invocations as inputs.

So you are seeing the unexpected results for count because the input of the final reduce call is not the full mapper results of 604 rows. Instead the input is the output of some previous invocations of the reduce function.

To fix this, you need to go back to your map function and change the output to a format that the reducer can also use as an output. It can be the same format as your current reducer output but the values are a summary for one document only. Try the following in your map function:

```
emit("ALL" , {total : 1, count : this.libres == 0 ? 1 : 0} )
```

Then your reducer needs to sum values of `total` and `count`, always returning an object of the same format, and you should get the expected values.

```
result = { total: 0, count:0 };
for (var i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
    result.total += values[i].total;
    result.count += values[i].count;
}
return result;
```